# NHibernate RowCountInt64 returns wrong count with transformed query

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-3

I am experiencing a weird error while executing an NHibernate Query.
I have a query of type `IQueryOver<ExternalUser, ExternalUser>` which is filtered and transformed (using DistinctRootEntity, which i am guessing is causing the problem). I create the query like this:

```
List<Guid> companyList = /* some guids */
Company company = null;
var query = _session.QueryOver<ExternalUser>()
                    .JoinAlias(x => x.Companies, () => company)
                    .Where(() => company.Id.IsIn(companyList))
                    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
```

When i execute `query.RowCountInt64()` i get 4.

When i execute `query.List()` i get 3 items back.

I have also tried `query.ToRowCountInt64Query().List<long>().Sum()` which also gives me 4.

I also tried `query.ToRowCountInt64Query().FutureValue<long>().Value`which also gives me 4.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that works:

```
totalCount = query.Clone()
                  .Select(Projections.CountDistinct<User>(x => x.Id))
                  .SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

...but my solution restricts me to Int32 which i'm not happy about. It will probably suffice in the implementation where i'm using it, but there might be cases elsewhere where long is needed, so any other suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The only thing i didn't like with the solution above was that it returned an int, so with some digging, i managed to fix that with another projection class:

```
public class Int64CountProjection : CountProjection
{
    protected internal Int64CountProjection(string prop) : base(prop) {}
    protected internal Int64CountProjection(IProjection projection) : base(projection) {}

    public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        return new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int64 };
    }

    public static CountProjection Distinct<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        return new Int64CountProjection(ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(expression.Body)).SetDistinct();
    }
}
```

...and with this class i can get my count like this (which could be refined further with an extension method, but this is enough for me):

```
totalCount = query.Clone()
                  .Select(Int64CountProjection.Distinct<User>(x => x.Id))
                  .SingleOrDefault<long>();
```

**EDIT #2**
I couldn't leave well alone, so i implemented an extension method aswell:

```
     public static long CorrectRowCount<TRoot>(this IQueryOver<TRoot> query) where TRoot : IEntity
     {
         return query.Clone()
                     .Select(Int64CountProjection.Distinct<TRoot>(x => x.Id))
                     .ClearOrders()
                     .Skip(0)
                     .Take(RowSelection.NoValue)
                     .SingleOrDefault<long>();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems be `Transformers.DistinctRootEntity` is natural you get 4 in row count, and 3 on a list. The `DistinctRootEntity` works when the query has been executed retuning 4 rows and removing duplicated in memory.

You can use `query.RowCountInt64()` with the correct query.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Clones the QueryOver, removes orders and paging, and projects the row-count
//     (Int64) for the query
IQueryOver<TRoot, TRoot> ToRowCountInt64Query();

//
// Summary:
//     Short for ToRowCountInt64Query().SingleOrDefault<long>()
long RowCountInt64();
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the row count methods you describe remove  any distinct projections i have done, which means that the count i get is not the same as the number of items i get. I need the row count to be accurate (not counting cartesian products) since i'm using this in a paged list.